# Python error pop up not working

Tags: python-2.7, exception, try-except

Writing code and I broke it somehow and can't remember what was previously working, only been using python a few weeks and after working on this literally all day, I'm more than a little frustrated...

```
# A program to calculate delivery order totals

from graphics import *

#Error Window
def errorWindow():
errwin = GraphWin("Error", 200, 200)
errwin.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 4.0)
errwin.setBackground(color_rgb(33,158,87))
Text(Point(2, 3), "This is not a valid order").draw(errwin)
Text(Point(2, 2.5), "Please try again").draw(errwin)
outline = Rectangle(Point(1.5,1), Point(2.5,2))
outline.setFill('white')
outline.draw(errwin)
okbutton = Text(Point(2,1.5),"OK")
okbutton.draw(errwin)
done=errwin.getMouse()
if (done.getX() > 1.5 and done.getX() < 2.5):
    errwin.close()

def main():    
    win = GraphWin("Brandi's Bagel House", 500, 500)
    win.setCoords(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 10.0)
    win.setBackground(color_rgb(33,158,87))

#Banner
    banner = Rectangle(Point(0, 8), Point(10, 10))
    banner.setFill(color_rgb(97,76,26))
    banner.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
    banner.draw(win)

#Logo Image
    circ = Circle(Point(1,9), .65)
    circ.setFill('white')
    circ.setOutline('white')
    circ.draw(win)

    circ2 = Circle(Point(1,9), .6)
    circ2.setFill(color_rgb(33,158,87))
    circ2.setOutline(color_rgb(33,158,87))
    circ2.draw(win)

    bigb = Text(Point(1, 9),"B")
    bigb.setStyle('bold italic')
    bigb.setTextColor('white')
    bigb.setFace('courier')
    bigb.setSize(28)
    bigb.draw(win)

#Horizontal Lines
    Line(Point(0,2.25), Point(10,2.25)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(0,4.25), Point(10,4.25)).draw(win)
    Line(Point(0,6.25), Point(10,6.25)).draw(win)

#Text
    title = Text(Point(4,9), "Delivery Orders:")
    title.setSize(20)
    title.setTextColor('white')
    title.draw(win)

    Text(Point(1.5,7), "Bagels:").draw(win)

    whitetext = Text(Point(3,7.5), "White")
    whitetext.setSize(10)
    whitetext.draw(win)

    wheattext = Text(Point(5,7.5), "Wheat")
    wheattext.setSize(10)
    wheattext.draw(win)

    Text(Point(1.5,5), "Toppings:").draw(win)

    creamtext = Text(Point(3,5.8), "Cream")
    creamtext.setSize(10)
    creamtext.draw(win)

    cheesetext = Text(Point(3,5.5), "Cheese")
    cheesetext.setSize(10)
    cheesetext.draw(win)

    buttertext = Text(Point(5,5.5), "Butter")
    buttertext.setSize(10)
    buttertext.draw(win)

    jellytext = Text(Point(7,5.5), "Jelly")
    jellytext.setSize(10)
    jellytext.draw(win)

    Text(Point(1.5,3), "Coffee:").draw(win)

    regtext = Text(Point(3,3.5), "Regular")
    regtext.setSize(10)
    regtext.draw(win)

    decaftext = Text(Point(5,3.5), "Decaf")
    decaftext.setSize(10)
    decaftext.draw(win)

    Text(Point(7,1.5), "Subtotal:").draw(win)
    Text(Point(7,1), "Tax:").draw(win)
    Text(Point(7,0.5), "Total:").draw(win)

#input bagel
    bagel1 = Entry(Point(3,7), 3)
    bagel1.setText("0")
    bagel1.draw(win)

    bagel2 = Entry(Point(5,7), 3)
    bagel2.setText("0")
    bagel2.draw(win)

#input topping
    top1 = Entry(Point(3,5), 3)
    top1.setText("0")
    top1.draw(win)

    top2 = Entry(Point(5,5), 3)
    top2.setText("0")
    top2.draw(win)

    top3 = Entry(Point(7,5), 3)
    top3.setText("0")
    top3.draw(win)

#input coffee

    coff1 = Entry(Point(3,3), 3)
    coff1.setText("0")
    coff1.draw(win)

    coff2 = Entry(Point(5,3), 3)
    coff2.setText("0")
    coff2.draw(win)

#Calculate Button
    outer1 = Rectangle(Point(4.2,0.6), Point(5.8,1.4))
    outer1.setFill('white')
    outer1.draw(win)
    button = Text(Point(5,1),"Calculate")
    button.draw(win)

#Quit Buttons
    outer2 = Rectangle(Point(9,9.2), Point(9.95,9.95))
    outer2.setFill('white')
    outer2.draw(win)
    button = Text(Point(9.5,9.6),"Quit")
    button.draw(win)

#Output
    subtotaloutput = Text(Point(9,1.5), "$0.00")
    subtotaloutput.draw(win)

    taxoutput = Text(Point(9,1), "$0.00")
    taxoutput.draw(win)

    totaloutput = Text(Point(9,0.5), "$0.00")
    totaloutput.draw(win)

#calculations
    whitebagel = eval(bagel1.getText())
    whitetotal = whitebagel* 1.25

    wheatbagel = eval(bagel2.getText())
    wheattotal = wheatbagel*1.50

    creamcheese = eval(top1.getText())
    creamtotal = creamcheese* 0.50

    butter = eval(top2.getText())
    buttertotal = butter*0.25

    jelly = eval(top3.getText())
    jellytotal = jelly*0.75

    regularcoff = eval(coff1.getText())
    regulartotal = regularcoff*1.25

    decafcoff = eval(coff2.getText())
    decaftotal = decafcoff*1.25

    click = win.getMouse()

    if (click.getX() > 4.2 and click.getX() < 5.8 and (whitebagel >0 or wheatbagel >0)):

        subtotal = whitetotal+wheattotal+creamtotal+buttertotal+jellytotal+regulartotal+decaftotal
        tax = .06
        taxes = subtotal*tax
        total = taxes+subtotal

        subtotal = "$%0.2f" % (subtotal)
        taxes = "$%0.2f" % (taxes)
        total = "$%0.2f" % (total)

        subtotaloutput.setText(subtotal)
        taxoutput.setText(taxes)
        totaloutput.setText(total)

        #Coffee Cup Image
        bottomoval = Oval(Point(0.7,0.4), Point(1.4, 0.7))
        bottomoval.setFill(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        bottomoval.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        bottomoval.draw(win)

        cup = Rectangle(Point(0.7,0.5), Point(1.4,1.3))
        cup.setFill(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        cup.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        cup.draw(win)

        topoval = Oval(Point(0.6,1.2), Point(1.5, 1.5))
        topoval.setFill('white')
        topoval.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        topoval.draw(win)

        coffee = Oval(Point(0.7,1.26), Point(1.4, 1.45))
        coffee.setFill(color_rgb(71,54,14))
        coffee.setOutline(color_rgb(71,54,14))
        coffee.draw(win)

        tinycirc = Circle(Point(1.05,0.8), .3)
        tinycirc.setFill(color_rgb(33,158,87))
        tinycirc.setOutline('white')
        tinycirc.draw(win)

        letter = Text(Point(1.05,0.8),"B")
        letter.setStyle('bold italic')
        letter.setTextColor('white')
        letter.setFace('courier')
        letter.setSize(17)
        letter.draw(win)

        #Bagel
        outerbagel = Oval(Point(1.8, 0.4), Point(2.7, 1))
        outerbagel.setFill(color_rgb(191,157,61))
        outerbagel.draw(win)

        shadow = Oval(Point(2.1, 0.7), Point(2.4, 0.8))
        shadow.setFill(color_rgb(130,102,26))
        shadow.draw(win)

    elif(click.getX() > 4.2 and click.getX() < 5.8 and whitebagel <1 and wheatbagel <1):
        errorWindow()

#End
    point = win.getMouse()
    if (point.getX() > 9 and point.getX() < 9.95):
        win.close()

main()
```

I need an error window to pop up if bagels are not selected with an order, as for this example coffee and toppings are not available for delivery without bagels.  I think I previously had this in a try/except, but now I can't get that to work either.  Either it won't calculate the totals and pops up or it calculates but still pops up the error, or nothing happens!  I also can't seem to find any direction on after closing the pop up, to go back to a functioning main window.  When I do close out the error window, the main window no longer works.  I'd like to be able to do that. Lastly I cannot use tkinter, only graphics.py.  I also apologize if anything is crudely done, so far it's the only way I know.  Thanks in advance for any advice.

I am still hoping someone will take pity on me and give me some direction as to where I'm going wrong with this code...  I have changed the part I'm having issues with but it's still not working:

```
   try:
    click = win.getMouse()

    if click.getX() > 4.2 and click.getX() < 5.8 and whitebagel >0 and wheatbagel >0:

        subtotal = whitetotal+wheattotal+creamtotal+buttertotal+jellytotal+regulartotal+decaftotal
        tax = .06
        taxes = subtotal*tax
        total = taxes+subtotal

        subtotal = "$%0.2f" % (subtotal)
        taxes = "$%0.2f" % (taxes)
        total = "$%0.2f" % (total)

        subtotaloutput.setText(subtotal)
        taxoutput.setText(taxes)
        totaloutput.setText(total)

        #Coffee Cup Image
        bottomoval = Oval(Point(0.7,0.4), Point(1.4, 0.7))
        bottomoval.setFill(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        bottomoval.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        bottomoval.draw(win)

        cup = Rectangle(Point(0.7,0.5), Point(1.4,1.3))
        cup.setFill(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        cup.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        cup.draw(win)

        topoval = Oval(Point(0.6,1.2), Point(1.5, 1.5))
        topoval.setFill('white')
        topoval.setOutline(color_rgb(97,76,26))
        topoval.draw(win)

        coffee = Oval(Point(0.7,1.26), Point(1.4, 1.45))
        coffee.setFill(color_rgb(71,54,14))
        coffee.setOutline(color_rgb(71,54,14))
        coffee.draw(win)

        tinycirc = Circle(Point(1.05,0.8), .3)
        tinycirc.setFill(color_rgb(33,158,87))
        tinycirc.setOutline('white')
        tinycirc.draw(win)

        letter = Text(Point(1.05,0.8),"B")
        letter.setStyle('bold italic')
        letter.setTextColor('white')
        letter.setFace('courier')
        letter.setSize(17)
        letter.draw(win)

        #Bagel
        outerbagel = Oval(Point(1.8, 0.4), Point(2.7, 1))
        outerbagel.setFill(color_rgb(191,157,61))
        outerbagel.draw(win)

        shadow = Oval(Point(2.1, 0.7), Point(2.4, 0.8))
        shadow.setFill(color_rgb(130,102,26))
        shadow.draw(win)

except:
    errorWindow()
```

I think i'm losing my mind here with the amount of time I've been trying to get this to work...

Comment: some of your code is improperly indented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, tkinter is not the way to go with graphics. It is kinda old and a lot of the concepts there will not turn out to be portable. Then again, use it if there is no other option...

Second, the code for ErrorWindow is not properly indented. When it is, I get at least one error popup. Possibly not in the right error condition.

Third, I would put some sort of check for the Y coordinates of the click as well, since you can trigger the Calculate button by clicking anywhere in its vertical column, like say the wheat text box.

Usually with a GUI there is some sort of event loop for processing multiple clicks. Something like:

```
while(True):
   click = win.getMouse()
   if calculate button:
       get text values
       if not bagels:
           errorWindow()
           continue
       calculate
   elif quit button:
       break
```

I made a modified version that had an event loop structured this way and I got it to give multiple totals, as well as putting up an error when I had no bagel order and then keeping going.